# Impute values based on other column max value and partition blocks on SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to replace some column values based on:

1. Another column max value.
2. Partition blocks.

The table looks like this:

| ID | PERIOD | DURATION (DAYS) | SIZE | COLOR | BLOCK_SIZE | BLOCK_COLOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9887 | 201810 | 10 | 1 | NULL | 1 | 1 |
| 9887 | 201810 | 15 | NULL | NULL | 1 | 1 |
| 9887 | 201808 | 100 | NULL | NULL | 4 | 1 |
| 9887 | 201808 | 90 | 3 | NULL | 4 | 1 |
| 9887 | 201808 | 50 | 1 | NULL | 4 | 1 |
| 9887 | 201808 | 10 | 5 | 7 | 4 | 1 |

Where I have:

- Multiple IDs.
- Multiple Periods.
- 2 characteristics (Size and Color).
- The duration of that characteristics before they changed.
- Block columns to identify the changes.

I need to impute Size and Color based on the max value in Duration within every partition block. The final result should look like this:

| ID | PERIOD | DURATION (DAYS) | SIZE | COLOR | BLOCK_SIZE | BLOCK_COLOR | SIZE2 | COLOR2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9887 | 201810 | 10 | 1 | NULL | 1 | 1 | 1 | 7 |
| 9887 | 201810 | 15 | NULL | NULL | 1 | 1 | 1 | 7 |
| 9887 | 201808 | 100 | NULL | NULL | 4 | 1 | 3 | 7 |
| 9887 | 201808 | 90 | 3 | NULL | 4 | 1 | 3 | 7 |
| 9887 | 201808 | 50 | 1 | NULL | 4 | 1 | 3 | 7 |
| 9887 | 201808 | 10 | 5 | 7 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 7 |

What I've done so far is trying to use FIRST_VALUE() to accomplish the desire result.

```
SELECT
 ID, PERIOD, DURATIONS, SIZE, COLOR, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_COLOR

 ,FIRST_VALUE(SIZE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, BLOCK_SIZE ORDER BY DURATIONS DESC) AS SIZE2
 ,FIRST_VALUE(COLOR) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, BLOCK_COLOR ORDER BY DURATIONS DESC) AS COLOR2
```

This is what I'm getting:

| ID | PERIOD | DURATION (DAYS) | SIZE | COLOR | BLOCK_SIZE | BLOCK_COLOR | SIZE2 | COLOR2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9887 | 201810 | 10 | 1 | NULL | 1 | 1 | 1 | 7 |
| 9887 | 201810 | 15 | NULL | NULL | 1 | 1 | 1 | 7 |
| 9887 | 201808 | 100 | NULL | NULL | 4 | 1 | NULL | 7 |
| 9887 | 201808 | 90 | 3 | NULL | 4 | 1 | NULL | 7 |
| 9887 | 201808 | 50 | 1 | NULL | 4 | 1 | NULL | 7 |
| 9887 | 201808 | 10 | 5 | 7 | 4 | 1 | NULL | 7 |

How could I get the correct values?

Comment: Your initial table and second table doesn't have the same value in last Color field. Also, the logic makes very little sense... Is it the largest duration where size / color isn't NULL that should be copied to whole block?

Comment: are the values copied forward or / and backwards for periods?

Comment: Yes, you want to keep the number with the largest duration for every block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not too far off, just needed to fix so NULLS are sorted last:

```sql
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(Color) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, BLOCK_COLOR ORDER BY CASE WHEN Color IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END /*!*/, [DURATION (DAYS)] DESC) AS color
,   FIRST_VALUE(Size) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, BLOCK_SIZE ORDER BY CASE WHEN Size IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END /*!*/, [DURATION (DAYS)] DESC) AS size
,   *
    from (
        VALUES  (9887, 201810, 10, N'1', NULL, 1, 1, 1, 7)
        ,   (9887, 201810, 15, NULL, NULL, 1, 1, 1, 7)
        ,   (9887, 201808, 100, NULL, NULL, 4, 1, 3, 7)
        ,   (9887, 201808, 90, N'3', NULL, 4, 1, 3, 7)
        ,   (9887, 201808, 50, N'1', NULL, 4, 1, 3, 7)
        ,   (9887, 201808, 10, N'5', N'7', 4, 1, 3, 7)
    ) t (ID,PERIOD,[DURATION (DAYS)],SIZE,COLOR,BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_COLOR,SIZE2,COLOR2)
```